# Replace a certain sequence with NA in R?

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a data frame in the form

```
Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6     Set_7
abc89     abc62     4:5       abc513    abc512    abc81     abc10
abc6      pop       abc11     abc4      giant     1:3        abc15
abc90     abc16     abc123    abc33     abc22     abc08     9
11:1      abc15     abc72     abc36     abc57     abc9      abc55
```

I would like to turn any cell that starts with "abc" to NA. I would also like to turn any cell that has a colon in it, into NA. I would like my output to be a data.frame. How can this be done easily in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `grep` to get the index of the elements that start with `abc`, and `replace` it by looping (`lapply`) through the columns

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) replace(x, grep('^abc', x), NA))
df1
#  Row1 Row2 Row3 Row4  Row5 Row6 Row7
#1 <NA> <NA>   45 <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2 <NA>  pop <NA> <NA> giant   13 <NA>
#3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>    9
#4  111 <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

NOTE: It is not clear why the columns are named as 'Row'

#### Update

For the new condition i.e. to any element that starts with `abc` or that contains `:`, you can use `|` in `grep` (as @Moix mentioned in the comments)

```
 df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) replace(x, grep('^abc|:', x), NA))
 is.data.frame(df2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

By using `[]`, we are keeping the same structure as the original dataset 'df2' while we replace the elements in the columns.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row1 = c("abc89", "abc6", "abc90", "111"),
Row2 = c("abc62", 
"pop", "abc16", "abc15"), Row3 = c("45", "abc11", "abc123", "abc72"
), Row4 = c("abc513", "abc4", "abc33", "abc36"), Row5 = c("abc512", 
"giant", "abc22", "abc57"), Row6 = c("abc81", "13", "abc08", 
"abc9"), Row7 = c("abc10", "abc15", "9", "abc55")), .Names = c("Row1", 
"Row2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row5", "Row6", "Row7"), 
class = "data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, -4L))

 df2 <- structure(list(Set_1 = c("abc89", "abc6", "abc90", "11:1"), 
  Set_2 = c("abc62", 
 "pop", "abc16", "abc15"), Set_3 = c("4:5", "abc11", "abc123", 
 "abc72"), Set_4 = c("abc513", "abc4", "abc33", "abc36"),
  Set_5 = c("abc512", 
 "giant", "abc22", "abc57"), Set_6 = c("abc81", "1:3", "abc08", 
 "abc9"), Set_7 = c("abc10", "abc15", "9", "abc55")), .Names = c("Set_1", 
 "Set_2", "Set_3", "Set_4", "Set_5", "Set_6", "Set_7"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: There are also some sequences that are like "87:55" and "7:132", basically I would like to turn any cell that has a colon into an NA as well. Thoughts?

Comment: @Evan Just update the regex to also search for the colon: `'^abc|:'`

Comment: @Evan Updated Based on Moix comments.

Comment: @Moix Thanks for the comments

Comment: Thanks, is the output a matrix?

Comment: @Evan It is a data.frame as the original dataset.  You can check it `is.matrix(df2)`

Comment: It says false when I do is.data.frame, how can i change that?

Comment: @Evan Can you check whether your initial dataset is `matrix`.  If it is matrix, the lapply won't work as showed.   Can you show the `str(yourinitialdata)`

Comment: its a list when i class it

Comment: @Evan `lapply` will work on `list`.  Then you may need `do.call(cbind, lapply(...`